# How does RAG (Retrieval Augmented Generation ) work around limited context length?

Tags: information-retrieval, text-generation, llm, prompt-engineering

My understanding of the RAG pipeline can be summarized with the following diagram:[image: diagram]

I understand steps 1-7 splits and vectorizes an external text data source into chunks and steps 8-11 retrieves **n** relevant chunks based off the user input query and some measure of vector similarity between text chunks and query.

What I'm not sure of is steps 12-13.

I am currently building a RAG chatbot using llama 2 and have tried prompting using the following
format:

> Given the following context: {***insert text chunks***} and no other information, answer the question:{***user input query***}.

The issue I'm running into is that I run into max prompt length errors due to the size and number of retrieved text chunks used in the prompt. What solutions are available?

Note- I'm trying not to use APIs like replicate.com to host the model.

Comment: Can you share the article or tutorial you are following for building the RAG chatbot usiing llama 2? I have build a similar RAG system using Falcon 7B and I think llama 2 will be much more suitable. I can share my RAG with you as well if you want!

Comment: @spectre if you don't mind hosting the model remotely, this [getting started with llama 2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes/blob/main/examples/Getting_to_know_Llama.ipynb) was what i used to get started. if you want to download the model itself you have to request permission from [meta](https://ai.meta.com/resources/models-and-libraries/llama-downloads/) (very easy) And yeah, I'm also kinda new to RAG so I would love to have a look at what you worked on

Answer (score 1):

There are two generic solutions/ post-processing steps to work around hitting the max_token limit irrespective of the *model/ LLM* you are consuming in *langchain*.

- Retain the *top_n* matches or chunks based on similarity scores where *top_n* would depend on the average chunk size and *max_token* restriction of the LLM in consumption.
- Extract only relevant part of the document returned from vector search. You can look into this [langchain blog](https://blog.langchain.dev/improving-document-retrieval-with-contextual-compression/) for Contextual Compression.

Comment: After looking into Contextual Compression, it seems that there are 2 main ways documents are compressed
1) `Prompt an LLM to extract only relevant parts of each document based on input query`
2) `Break the document down into smaller documents and filter via vector similarity score with input query`

While both methods should work I was hoping for a more novel approach because the solutions feel like I'm using RAG to fix RAG